# Ruby method parameters?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm new to Ruby and I'm completely disgusted. Why does the following code:

```
def some_method(v=1) 10*v end

puts (some_method (1).next)
puts  some_method (1).next
```

Evaluate to:

```
20
11
```

Comment: Which Ruby version? In 1.9.3 both lines return 20.

Comment: In `2.0.0` for both cases it returns 20 as well.

Comment: @Jefffrey: So Jefrey do you think the result is obvious looking at the code? Do you think such syntax / parsing rules are clear? Its nice, that in ruby > 1.9 its fixed.

Comment: Cann't reproduce. Both expressions return 20. Space character can influence evaluation order. If you put it after some_method `1.next` is evaluated first then passed as argument. If you omit the space, `(1)` is passed as argument and `next` is called on its result. Consistent & logical.

Comment: @danilo2 It looks like in Ruby < 1.9 space cann't change evaluation order, but if it's docummented and you even got warnings I see no issue here.

Comment: @danilo2 Hey bro, You've raised the fury of Ruby programmers with your comment ;-) Are you forced to programme in Ruby against your wishes? Let me tell you I've programmed in many languages and absolutely love Ruby. This is many people's experience. Please give it another chance and I'm sure you'll change your mind.

Comment: @danilo2, as you encounter different languages, you'll find there are stylistic differences in how code for that language is written, but consistently you'll find that parenthesis are used to override the interpreter or compiler's understanding of its order of precedence, so you can force it to behave. You're running afoul of Ruby's leniency towards not needing parenthesis around method parameters and spaces. `method(parm,...)` is safer than `method param, ...`, so tell the interpreter how it should read your code. Blocks with methods only make this worse.

Comment: I don't see how people can say that Danilo wrote bad code. It is documented to work a certain and it didn't. Clearly a bug in his ruby version. Maybe bringing it here isn't the best place, but if that is the case say so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby 1.8.7, the first example evaluates to 20, because that is the correct behavior.

Let's break it down. We start with

```
puts (some_method (1).next)
```

We then add the missing/implicit parentheses:

```
puts((some_method((1).next)))
```

Let's split this out a bit into its separate parts:

```
puts(
  (
    some_method(
      (1).next
    )
  )
)
```

Ruby starts from the inside, evaluating `(1)`. The value of that is, well, `1`, so we get

```
puts(
  (
    some_method(
      1.next
    )
  )
)
```

Next up, `1.next`, which returns `2`:

```
puts(
  (
    some_method(
      2
    )
  )
)
```

Thus, Ruby passes `2` as the parameter to `some_method`, which then multiplies by 10 and returns the correct value, `20`:

```
puts(
  (
    20
  )
)
```

This - unsurprisingly outputs `20`.

What you probably wanted to write is

```
puts some_method(1).next
```

which outputs `11`. The space you've added between the method name and the parenthesis is significant.

Interestingly, if you are indeed running 1.8.7, you actually get a warning in that last example of yours:

```
>> puts some_method (1).next
(irb):13: warning: don't put space before argument parentheses
11
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# first case
puts (some_method (1).next)
```

=> through the () around some_method (1).next everything gets wrapped into the puts.

```
some_method (1).next => (1).next => 2 => 2*10 => 20

# second case
puts some_method (1).next
```

=> here is no "wrapper" around the puts

```
some_method (1).next => 1*10 => 10 => 10.next => 11
```

**UPDATE:** (ruby 1.9.2-p290)

Interesting difference between "with space" and "without space" (okay, that´s no answer, that´s another question I think :))

```
irb(main):011:0> puts some_method (1).next
20
=> nil
irb(main):012:0> puts some_method(1).next
11
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Under jruby-1.6.7.2 in ruby 1.8 compatibility mode, I see:

```
20
11
```

Whereas in 1.9 compatibility mode I see

```
20
20
```

I suspect that there was a change to the precedence operators.